# Mono and Microsoft.Http web client

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, mono, apache2

I'm trying to port a MVC3 .NET project from VS to Mono and I been able to set up apache correctly and am able to build my code using local MVC3 references.

My problem now is I make a few api calls to a web service to populate some user info before the index page displays, but when mono/apache tries to hit my web service using Microsoft.Http I get an error.

Here is my code:

```
 public T HttpGet<T>(string requestPath, int minutes)
    {
        return this.Get(requestPath).Return<T>();
    }
```

and here is the error:

[image]

Comment: What version of mono are you running? The latest? It seems pretty clear from the error message you are getting and the Google search I did that the feature you requested is not implemented in the version of mono you are running.

Comment: I am running the latest stable version of mono 2.10.8. Could you give me the reference your google result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.mono-project.com/FAQ:_Technical

If you read this through you will see that not every Microsoft .NET API is available on Mono.